# How to navigate to a specific IBM Cloud resource using CRN?

Tags: ibm-cloud

Is it possible to construct a URL from CRN like below, that will take me directly to the identified resource?

Example:

> crn:v1:bluemix:public:containers-kubernetes:us-south:a/59bcbfa6ea2f006b4ed7094c1a08dcdd:8042b2a8af6a4a5cbf6dbe09e07311d2:worker:kube-hou02-pa8042b2a8af6a4a5cbf6dbe09e07311d2-w1:

Source: [IBM Bluemix Cloud Resource Names (CRN)](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/overview/crn.html#crn)

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is not too clear, below link can suggest how you should use CRN to identify a resource. If you mean something else then please update your question accordingly.

[CRN Usage](https://dataplatform.ibm.com/analytics/notebooks/v2/656c7d43-7ccd-4e50-a3c0-bbc37c001132/view?access_token=baaa77ad715e17a8f823615d45431329fde0fe92fecb85abb9fc55a877939fe8)

**NOTE**: I dont have comment access till now or else I would have preferred to mention this as a comment.Cheers.